# Reading text file trough XMLHttpRequest produces syntax error in text file, works tough

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am reading a text file trough XMLHttpRequest inside Firefox trough the normal means, the text file consist of a single line of picture filenames seperated with a pipe symbol ('|').
Everything works in the end, my image list gets read, i can parse it just fine and load my pictures.

Here is the code for the curious.

```
bilderListeDatei.open("GET","./bilder/liste?nocachetrick="+jetzt.getTime(),true);

bilderListeDatei.onreadystatechange = function () 
{
    if (bilderListeDatei.readyState === 4) 
    {  
        if (bilderListeDatei.status === 200) 
        {  
            bilderListe = bilderListeDatei.responseText.split("|");
            elementeZuLaden += bilderListe.length;

            for(var i in bilderListe)
            {
                var j = bilder.push(new Image());
                bilder[j-1].onload = function() 
                                        {
                                            elementeGeladen++;
                                            if(elementeZuLaden == elementeGeladen){elementeLadenFertig = true;}
                                        }
                bilder[j-1].src = "./bilder/" + bilderListe[i];
                //alert(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As said the syntax error is produced inside my text file, not the code, that works flawlessly.
Any idea how i could get rid of that (ignored by the rest of the programm) error message?

EDIT:
The error message because it got mangled up in the comment:

```
Zeitstempel: 18.01.2013 14:15:01
Fehler: Syntax-Fehler
Quelldatei: http://192.168.2.102/seitenbastel/bilder/liste?nocachetrick=1358514901070
Zeile: 1, Spalte: 1
Quelltext:
65.jpg|67.jpg|69.jpg|71.jpg|73.jpg|75.jpg|77.jpg|79.jpg|81.jpg|83.jpg|85.jpg|87.jpg|89.jpg|91.jpg|93.jpg|95.jpg|97.jpg
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? You really should not use a for in loop on an array.

Comment: Edited into the OP, comment section doesnt like formating.

Sorry, German browser. ;)

Comment: If you replace the content inside of `if (bilderListeDatei.status === 200)` with just a console statement saying you are there, does it produce the error? Does clearing the cache make any difference?

Comment: Nope, no error with just an alert("heyho"); in there. And clearing the cache brings nothing either.

Comment: So start to uncomment out lines in your if statement and see which one throws the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest will try to parse the results as XML, in general, to create the `responseXML` object.  Your data is presumably not XML.  You either need to tell the browser that in your `Content-Type` header (e.g. setting it to `text/plain` in your case) or tell the browser that you don't actually want a parsed DOM representation at all by setting `responseType = "text"` on the XHR object if you only plan to use the text.